# Populating a datagridview with read only values c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to populate my data grid view with read only rows. This didn't work:

```
RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Rows[i].ReadOnly = true;
```

Here is my code:

```
private void setUpListTableForGridView(int rows)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= Constans.AMOUNT_COLUMNS_IN_LIST; i++)
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgc = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Columns.Add(dgc);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++)
    {
        RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Rows.Add();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just set the `ReadOnly` flag?

Comment: make them from designer

Answer (score 0):

From your Form designer, you can disable editing:

[image]